# st_network_paths only generating node_path with single nodes

Tags: r, shortest-path, sfnetwork

I'm trying to generate a list of nodes on the shortest path between two nodes using `st_network_paths()`. However,  I only get a single value for the node index in `node_path`.

It works with toy data but not real world data. What needs to happen to make the real world, stream network, play ball?

Line data available [here](https://theriverstrust-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/josh_jones_theriverstrust_org/EV4fIUeCEutGllOW90jIPp4Bf1K_HuqRkJqRUiS9Ue3gUg?e=8LGMOa)

```
library(sfnetworks)
library(sf)
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)

ln <- st_read("river.gpkg")
    
net = as_sfnetwork(ln)

paths <- st_network_paths(net, 
                          from = 2,
                          to = 50)

# plot one path to check
node_path <- paths %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(node_paths) %>%
  unlist()

node_path

plot(net, col = "grey")
plot(slice(activate(net, "nodes"), 2), 
     col = "blue", add = TRUE)
plot(slice(activate(net, "nodes"), 50), 
     col = "red", add = TRUE)
plot(slice(activate(net, "nodes"), node_path), 
     col = "green", add = TRUE) # just recreates the node_path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to compute a path between two different branches in a directed network:

```r
# packages
library(sf) 
library(tidygraph)
library(sfnetworks)

# data
ln <- st_read("C:/Users/andre/Desktop/river.gpkg", quiet = TRUE)
net = as_sfnetwork(ln)

# plot
par(mar = rep(0, 4))
plot(net)
plot(net %N>% slice(2, 50), add = TRUE, cex = 2, col = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If the desired paths can also be calculated travelling "backwards", you can set the argument `directed` in `as_sfnetwork` to `FALSE` (i.e. `net = as_sfnetwork(ln, directed = FALSE)` and run the same code as before. You can recognise this type of problems since `st_network_paths()` returns a warning message like

```r
> paths <- st_network_paths(
+   net, 
+   from = 2, 
+   to = 50
+ )
Warning message:
In shortest_paths(x, from, to, weights = weights, output = "both",  :
  At structural_properties.c:4745 :Couldn't reach some vertices
```